# Twitch number online streamers in Chrome Icon in Plugin

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, twitch

I want to create plugin in Chrome. I do almost all what I wanted, except online number of streamers in Chrome plugin icon.

I put text "Check"

[Link to preview 'Check'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5xOW.jpg)

but I would like to see in this place online number of streamers, or if someone from streamers are online, then will be text "On".

Can someone help me?

To put text in that place is code:
In .js copy line:

chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: 'On'});

I try somethink like this:

**popup.js**

```
var clientID = 'API-KEY';
var baseKraken = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/';

function getKrakenAPI(endpoint, data, method) {
    return $.ajax({
            url: baseKraken + endpoint,
            method: method,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Client-ID': clientID,
                Accept: 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json'
            }
        });
}

getKrakenAPI(
        'streams',
        {
            channel: [ 'ivelios_christopher', 'esl_sc2' ]
        }
    )
.done(function(data) {
        if(data._total > 0) {

    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText( { text: "On" } );

        }
    });
```

But from some reason don`t work, any tips/help?

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "My Bookmarks",
  "version": "1.1",
  "description": "A browser action with a popup dump of all bookmarks, including search, add, edit and delete.",
  "permissions": [
    "bookmarks",
        "*://*.twitch.tv/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "My Bookmarks",
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
"background":
{
    "scripts":["jquery-3.2.1.min.js"],
  "scripts":["popup.js"]

}
}
```

**popup.html**

```
    <html>
    <head>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="popup.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
      <iframe src="#" height="550" width="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks.

Best,
Ivelios

Comment: I edit question.

Comment: Check for any errors in the console by debugging the popup: rightclick it and then Inspect or simply open the popup as a normal tab: `chrome-extension://ID/popup.html` (replace ID with your extension ID).

Comment: I have some errors ;[ `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at getKrakenAPI (popup.js:5)
    at popup.js:17`

Comment: I add jquery-3.2.1.min.js localhost in manifest.json, and popup.html, the same error.

Comment: I change it. New error: `Uncaught TypeError: getKrakenAPI(...).success is not a function
    at popup.js:23` iframe open page with main content.

Comment: I don't know Kraken API, but your manifest's "permissions" value is missing `"https://api.twitch.tv/"`

Comment: How add permissions in manifest.json ? I`m noob with dev chrome.

Comment: Check the [Declare Permisisons docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) which is part of the [Manifest File Format](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) for actual format and sample:

"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "bookmarks",
  "http://www.blogger.com/",
  "http://*.google.com/",
  "unlimitedStorage"
],

Comment: Thx for tips, I edit manifest.json and popup.js. Now is not error, but setBadgeText is not display "On". Maybe in chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText( { text: "On" } ); change "On" to dynamic, but I don`t know how, any tips?